# Expressing a hierarchy within a type-system with ADT and (possibly) GADT

Tags: compiler-construction, ocaml, type-systems

In my type-system I want to support promotable types, where an `Int` would be promoted to a `Double` if used with division, and `String` to `StringBuffer` if used with concatenation. Can I express this with agebraic data-types, so the compiler would throw a type error if it tried to promote the wrong type?

E.g.:

```
type ty =
  | Int
  | Double
  | String
  | StringBuffer
  | Promotable of ref ty
```

*But*, `Int` can only be promoted to `Double`, not `StringBuffer` or `String`.

Using GADT:

```
type _ ty =
  | Int : arith ty
  | Double : arith ty
  | String : text ty
  | StringBuffer : text ty
  | Promotable of ref ty : ... ??
```

Where `arith` and `text` need to be a type "family" (kind, type class)? Can I express this in OCaml?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**: Example usage based on answer below:

```
let promote : type a. a ty -> a ty = function
  | Promotable (Int, IntToDouble) ->Double (* StringBuffer here would not type-check *)
  | Promotable (String, StringToStringBuffer) -> StringBuffer
  | t -> t
```

Comment: @objmagic mutable field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have another GADT describing what the hierarchy is and then expect a proof to be handed to you when someone tries to promote a value. E.g.:

```
type arith
type text

type (_ , _) lessThan =
  | IntToDouble          : (arith, arith) lessThan
  | StringToStringBuffer : (text, text) lessThan

type _ ty =
  | Int          : arith ty
  | Double       : arith ty
  | String       : text ty
  | StringBuffer : text ty
  | Promotable   : 'ref ty * ('ref, 'promo) lessThan -> 'promo ty
```

Comment: Nice! But how would I actually use this, say, for a function that takes `Promotable Int` and returns `Promotable Double`?

Comment: Added an example usage in my question.

Comment: Does that typecheck? It looks suspicious to me. The returned values should be `Double` and `StringBuffer`, I think (it does not really make sense to "promote" a `Double` with `IntToDouble`: it's not an `Int`, it's already a `Double`!).

Comment: Yes, it works, but maybe you're right still. `Double` is not promotable.

Comment: I updated my edit. But it seems it's possible to promote `Double` to `Int` this way, too? Or indeed any `arith` to any other `arith`, so there's is no hierarchy in this solution. Maybe it can be solved using two different kinds of `arith`? But then you would have to hardcode all relations. Well, that might be necessary anyway.